# TP4056 input current

Tags: current

The input voltage should be roughly 5 volts for the TP4056 charger module with protection. 
How much is the maximum input current for this module?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! What does the datasheet say?

Answer (score 2):

See the (a) datasheet like [TP4056 datasheet](https://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Prototyping/TP4056.pdf), first page:

Absolute maximum ratings:

- BAT Pin Current：1200mA
- PROG Pin Current：1200uA

However, it's better to stick to the Electrical Characteristics page on the next page.